# Set the language of the keyboard appearing on webview textarea click in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, webview

Whenever I click on textarea on the webview, it displays a keyboard which is showing me characters in English, but whenever I start typing, my typed characters get converted into some other language (Chinese) and on rendering only that other language words are rendered instead of English.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 1.6 or higher then go to 
menu>setting>language & keyboard and uncheck all the check box expect android keyboard.
may this help you?